# Does Mantra of Retribution still damage enemies when Serenity is active?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

Mantra of Retribution returns 40% damage to enemies. Serenity makes you invulnerable for 3 seconds. If I am invulnerable from Serenity while Mantra of Retribution is active and an enemy attacks me, will he receive damage from the Mantra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the Mantra will not damage your enemies while Serenity is active.

I just tested this on some low-level monsters, and regardless of which was activated first, the monsters took no damage from the reflected attacks while Serenity was active.